# Mass, energy, and entropy.

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, mass-energy

I have a seemingly simple question about the relation between these three that for some reason doesn't make sense to me. If entropy is the disorder of a system, then a low entropy state is one of higher energy. As we know, mass is energy. From here we must say that the more mass something has, the lower its entropy because the mass can be converted to energy. Why then are black holes, the most massive things known, considered to be of such high entropy?

Comment: Entropy is not directly related to total energy or total mass, I think is what you've confused here. Consider an isolated box of gas - the energy inside the box is fixed as it is a closed system. The entropy of this box can depend on the arrangement of gas particles, which can alter the available energy that can do work but not the total energy.

Comment: "...the energy inside the box is fixed as it is a closed system." I think this is the conceptual issue I have. To me it doesn't make sense to differentiate energy and entropy since it takes work to get the energy from a system. If the particles are arranged in a low entropy state, then only a small amount of energy (or none) is needed to release that energy. If the particles are in a high entropy state, then to release that same energy they must first be transformed to a low entropy state which itself takes energy. This should make us consider the former arrangement one of higher energy.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it takes work to get the energy from a system". Can you give an example of this, or "transformation to a low entropy state"?

Comment: A perpetual motion machine is not possible because entropy increases, which can also be stated as available energy decreases. We can say the energy of the box is conserved when the gas evolves to a high entropy state, but if we want the system to do work (extract energy from it) then we must rearrange it into a low entropy state, which takes energy to do (Maxwells demon). A transformation to a low entropy state would be to tightly arrange all of the gas in a small location, causing a raised temperature and pressure, which can be used for work.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. The thing is, you can inject / extract energy from a system without necessarily altering entropy: changes in heat (particle speeds for simplicity) correlate to changes in internal energy (1st law) - eg, a uniform temperature difference between the box and it's surroundings would result with a flow of heat energy without affecting the entropy of the box. In Maxwell's Demon, the resulting increase in available energy is offset by the energy required to perform the separation in the first place - like using one battery to charge another.

Comment: Just adding to "without affecting the entropy of the box" - there may be internal temperature gradients as the outside cools/heats faster than inside, but this aside the statement holds.

Comment: This may seem like a reach, but in what way is having more particles (demon) and a higher temperature/energy in a confined space not a lower entropy situation than less particles and lower temp? If things naturally evolve to a higher entropy state, then we would expect with time for the particles and temp to evolve to equilibrium. If they spontaneously started moving fast and heating up, this would be like a massive fluctuation to lower entropy, whether or not we inject extra energy. If we don't consider this (an unnatural evolution to a less likely state) lower entropy, then what is the

Comment: point in speaking of entropy in physics? If we can define entropy as 'unavailable energy' (which it seems we are) then how is a higher temp and faster moving particles not an increase in available energy and therefore a decrease in entropy? Just saying the box is still in a 'likely' state doesn't say anything interesting because it isn't comparing itself to its actual history, but an arrangement that didn't exist.

Comment: Can't edit comment-to be clear, by 'likely' I mean as compared to an expected history of a box with the same amount of particles, motions, and temperature. If injecting energy in doesn't decrease entropy even though a 'natural fluctuation' to this state would be considered a lowering of entropy, then I don't see the point in using it as a description as all changes are natural. In other words, it is a rare an unexpected (low entropy) event for something to precisely inject energy into a system!

Comment: Sorry I just re-read your last comment... Events don't have an entropy, states do. The probability of a state, is the likelihood of finding a system in that state in general, whereas the probability of an event depends on some initial state. If the entropy of a system is large, it means it is in a state that has many permutations with the same (small) available internal energy. However a low entropy state has fewer permutations giving the same (large) available internal energy. Eg, there are fewer ways (low entropy) to arrange large heat gradients than small ones (high entropy).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed replies. I haven't had a chance to sit down and really give them thought but I will do so and respond.

Comment: Ok, but how those states evolve is the bases for the second law of thermo, so the same logic holds. Heat being injected into a system increases its energy, and if we say this doesn't decrease its entropy (by ignoring its history and only comparing its state to other possible arrangements of the same constituents) then we are ignoring the fact that the only way for it to have gotten to that state of higher energy is from a previous lower entropy state (either  a fluctuation or an energy injection). Seems circular. Again, spontaneous acceleration of all particles increases available energy...

Comment: Give me a bit of time to work through your response below. What I was getting at in my original question is that it seems to me that black hole entropy must be observer dependent. To an outside observer, there is no interior (since nothing past it can be accessed and used for work) so the entropy is on the area of the horizon. To someone who falls in, all of its surroundings are potentially usable to do work, so its entropy is lower.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few concepts to go through regarding entropy in thermodynamics - it's a tricky subject easy to conflate with probabilistic interpretations.

**Temperature vs Heat**

Temperature refers only to the particles' speeds. Increasing the temperature of an isolated system will increase the speeds of the particles, but does not of itself affect the entropy per se.

Contrast this with Heat, which most times is what is meant by talking about the *internal energy of a system*. The Heat of a system, is the total thermal energy - a warm box of gas has more heat than a cold one. But, Heat also relates to the quantity of particles - a large, warm box has more heat than a small box of the same temperature because there's more mass at that temperature. I don't know if it's right or not, but it helps me to think of Heat as 'thermal momentum' analogous to temperature being 'thermal speed'.

The difference is important, since the Work done by a thermodynamic system is proportional to a change in Heat content. That is, if you cannot construct a heat gradient, no work can be done.

**Entropy vs Internal Energy**

For something like Maxwell's Demon, you need to consider what happens to the heat content.

In a 'normal' situation the speeds of particles in a box of gas aren't going to be equal, but they'll approach a distribution that tends toward the average temperature. This means there is a set of particles at a lower-than-average speed and a set of particles at higher-than-average speed, but *these particles are not separated so no work can be extracted* - both sets of particles are occupying the same volume (the whole box of gas) so no significant heat gradient can be found to extract work from.

Maxwell's Demon, is a door / gatekeeper etc, that sifts particles such that these two sets end up apart from one another - say, the 'faster' particles on the left and the 'slower' particles on the right. The total energy has not changed (ignoring how the selection process works), the internal energy has not changed (particles are in different places but with their initial speeds), so what has changed?

The entropy - due to the re-arrangement, the internal energy (Heat) has been partitioned creating a gradient where there previously was none. This is despite the heat energy existing before in the same quantity. This means that a decrease in entropy, increased the amount of *available* energy in the form of heat.

Consider then, if the temperature distribution of the particles were larger - the same decrease in entropy would make available a larger proportion of the internal energy, as there would be a larger gradient possible.

Clearly, entropy relates to *available* internal energy. In this case the *total* internal energy is Heat, which is proportional to temperature.

**Entropy vs Mass / Energy**

Entropy on its own is not a measure of energy or mass, in fact mass itself is better related to Heat - changes in Heat correspond to changes in energy (and therefore to changes in mass).

**Information vs Entropy**

In Maxwell's Demon, this entropy isn't appearing from nowhere; we can't start with nothing and end up with something. In other words, what does the demon do to the system in a thermodynamic sense?

It adds 'information' to each particle it 'sorts' to either the left or the right. This same 'information' is then 'recovered' when the resulting liberated internal energy can be put to use.

In other words, the available internal energy (resulting from entropy / physical configuration) is in a very real sense describing the 'information' content as opposed to 'noise' or '*disorder*'.

To put it very simply - the more information is encoded in a physical system, the less entropy it has, or if you prefer the term, less disorder.

**Black Hole Entropy**

It is worth revisiting the 2nd law in context of the previous conclusion - entropy tends to increase, would imply that information tends to decrease.

A black hole is a collapsed object - one crushed into a point by it's own gravity. As a result there is no way to represent physical information that has fallen into the hole, as should any fall in the matter / energy making it up is crushed beyond recognition.

Then, if no information can survive (or be used) inside a black hole, it suggests that it is a state of maximum disorder - a state of maximum entropy.

**If decreases in entropy increase available energy, why do black holes have large entropy?**

To answer your question directly - changes in entropy do not correspond to changes in total energy. Lowering entropy makes it possible for internal energy to become useful, but this does not create internal energy or change the total energy.

Conversely, *increasing* entropy will make it harder to extract internal energy within a system until a point where no internal energy can be utilized at all - such as inside a black hole. Per above, changing entropy will not change the total energy, so you cannot form a black hole by changing entropy; in this context entropy is a *measure* of a black hole or some object's available internal energy and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a glass on the floor -> Entropy increases.
Drop another glass on the floor -> Entropy increases again.

From above we conclude that a big pile of broken glass contains more entropy than a small pile of broken glass. We also happen to know that a big pile of broken glass has larger mass than a small pile of broken glass.

Drop a glass on the floor -> Entropy increases.
Hammer the pieces of glass to smaller pieces -> Entropy increases again.

From above we conclude that breaking a solid to very small pieces causes a large increase of entropy. We also happen to know that breaking a solid to very small pieces increases the internal energy of the (former) solid.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from comments:

> how is a higher temp and faster moving particles not an increase in available energy and therefore a decrease in entropy?

Maybe higher temperature means more available energy *and* more unavailable energy! It definitely sometimes means that.

We have devices that decrease entropy of heat energy, in other words they make heat energy more "available". Heat pumps are those devices. They pump heat to higher temperature, in other words they make heat less entropic.

We also have devices that produce heat energy and entropy, Stoves and radiators are those kind of devices.

So here's advice to OP: Do not make too general conclusions, as entropy can be removed from heat energy, which will cause a rise of temperature. But also more heat and more entropy can be added to heat energy, which will cause a rise of temperature.

Answer (score -1):

Calling entropy "disorder" is somewhat misleading, it can also be described as the amount of area containing an amount of energy or even information. A black hole will contain a significant amount of quantum data in an incredibly small space, making them objects with high entropy. However this is a fixed amount of entropy and to continue the propagation of energy as is needed by the laws of thermodynamics, some of the particles containing this information will escape (look up hawking radiation).

Backing away from quantum mechanics and black holes and going to more simple terms of entropy (because simple to more complex is a boring way to teach). Imagine a drop of ink and a bowl of water, if we were to drop the ink into the water then it would spread until it was equally distributed throughout the water (maximum entropy). We would still have the same amount of ink throughout the entire bowl, but it would have mixed with the water. Entropy increases in the way that ink will only spread through the water, but will not slowly un-mix back into the drop that first entered the water.